# sccm 2012 r2 sp1 not pxe booting

Tags: sccm

I have a question that has been stumping me. I have Sccm 2012 r2 sp1 and I was able to image machines using pxe boot to deploy the task sequences for imaging.

When I load up any machine it will grab the Image from WDS but then kicks out when establishing a network connection. I have re added all nic drivers and updated the distribution points, But i still get the error

> Failed to download pxe variable file. Code(0x00000001)    TSPxe   7/13/2017 10:17:17 AM   912 (0x0390)
>   PxeGetPxeData failed with 0x80004005    TSPxe   7/13/2017 10:17:17 AM   912 (0x0390)

Here is the log file from the client machine.

> Set command line: "X:\sms\bin\x64\smstftp.exe" -i **ipaddress** get \SMSTemp\2017.07.13.10.15.24.0005.{B2F81AB5-D465-4D3A-8656-184732B4EC6D}.boot.var X:\sms\data\variables.dat    TSPxe   7/13/2017 10:16:30 AM   912 (0x0390)
>   Executing command line: "X:\sms\bin\x64\smstftp.exe" -i **ipaddress** get \SMSTemp\2017.07.13.10.15.24.0005.{B2F81AB5-D465-4D3A-8656-184732B4EC6D}.boot.var X:\sms\data\variables.dat   TSPxe   7/13/2017 10:16:30 AM   912 (0x0390)
>   hMap != 0, HRESULT=80070002 (e:\nts_sccm_release\sms\framework\tscore\environmentscope.cpp,493) TSBootShell 7/13/2017 10:16:52 AM   900 (0x0384)
>   m_pGlobalScope->open(), HRESULT=80070002 (e:\nts_sccm_release\sms\framework\tscore\environmentlib.cpp,335)  TSBootShell 7/13/2017 10:16:52 AM   900 (0x0384)
>   this->open(), HRESULT=80070002 (e:\nts_sccm_release\sms\framework\tscore\environmentlib.cpp,553)    TSBootShell 7/13/2017 10:16:52 AM   900 (0x0384)
>   Executing command line: X:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /k  TSBootShell 7/13/2017 10:16:52 AM   900 (0x0384)
>   The command completed successfully. TSBootShell 7/13/2017 10:16:52 AM   900 (0x0384)
>   Successfully launched command shell.    TSBootShell 7/13/2017 10:16:52 AM   900 (0x0384)
>   Process completed with exit code 1  TSPxe   7/13/2017 10:17:17 AM   912 (0x0390)
>   Succesfully removed firewall rule for Tftp  TSPxe   7/13/2017 10:17:17 AM   912 (0x0390)
>   uExitCode == 0, HRESULT=80004005 (e:\nts_sccm_release\sms\server\pxe\tspxe\tspxe.cpp,185)   TSPxe   7/13/2017 10:17:17 AM   912 (0x0390)
>   Failed to download pxe variable file. Code(0x00000001)  TSPxe   7/13/2017 10:17:17 AM   912 (0x0390)
>   PxeGetPxeData failed with 0x80004005    TSPxe   7/13/2017 10:17:17 AM   912 (0x0390)
>   HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(dwError), HRESULT=80004005 (e:\nts_sccm_release\sms\client\tasksequence\tsmbootstrap\tsmbootstraputil.cpp,1459)  TSPxe   7/13/2017 10:17:17 AM   912 (0x0390)
>   TSMBootstrapUtil::PxeGetPxeData(&bPxeBooted, sVariablesFile, sPxePasswd), HRESULT=80004005 (e:\nts_sccm_release\sms\client\tasksequence\tsmbootstrap\tsmediawizardcontrol.cpp,2572) TSPxe   7/13/2017 10:17:17 AM   912 (0x0390)
>   oTSMediaWizardControl.Run( sMediaRoot, true, sTSLaunchMode ), HRESULT=80004005 (e:\nts_sccm_release\sms\client\tasksequence\tsmbootstrap\tsmbootstrap.cpp,1098) TSPxe   7/13/2017 10:17:17 AM   912 (0x0390)
>   Execute( eExecutionEnv, sConfigPath, sTSXMLFile, uBootCount, &uExitCode ), HRESULT=80004005 (e:\nts_sccm_release\sms\client\tasksequence\tsmbootstrap\tsmbootstrap.cpp,1246)    TSPxe   7/13/2017 10:17:17 AM   912 (0x0390)
>   Exiting with return code 0x80004005 TSPxe   7/13/2017 10:17:17 AM   912 (0x0390)
>   hMap != 0, HRESULT=80070002 (e:\nts_sccm_release\sms\framework\tscore\environmentscope.cpp,493) TSPxe   7/13/2017 10:17:17 AM   912 (0x0390)
>   m_pGlobalScope->open(), HRESULT=80070002 (e:\nts_sccm_release\sms\framework\tscore\environmentlib.cpp,335)  TSPxe   7/13/2017 10:17:17 AM   912 (0x0390)
>   this->open(), HRESULT=80070002 (e:\nts_sccm_release\sms\framework\tscore\environmentlib.cpp,553)    TSPxe   7/13/2017 10:17:17 AM   912 (0x0390)
>   Execution complete. TSBootShell 7/13/2017 10:17:17 AM   904 (0x0388)
>   hMap != 0, HRESULT=80070002 (e:\nts_sccm_release\sms\framework\tscore\environmentscope.cpp,493) TSBootShell 7/13/2017 10:17:17 AM   904 (0x0388)
>   m_pGlobalScope->open(), HRESULT=80070002 (e:\nts_sccm_release\sms\framework\tscore\environmentlib.cpp,335)  TSBootShell 7/13/2017 10:17:17 AM   904 (0x0388)
>   this->open(), HRESULT=80070002 (e:\nts_sccm_release\sms\framework\tscore\environmentlib.cpp,553)    TSBootShell 7/13/2017 10:17:17 AM   904 (0x0388)
>   ::RegOpenKeyExW (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sKey.c_str(), 0, KEY_READ, &hSubKey), HRESULT=80070002 (e:\nts_sccm_release\sms\framework\tscore\utils.cpp,810)    TSBootShell 7/13/2017 10:17:17 AM   904 (0x0388)
>   RegOpenKeyExW is unsuccessful for Software\Microsoft\SMS\Task Sequence  TSBootShell 7/13/2017 10:17:17 AM   904 (0x0388)
>   GetTsRegValue() is unsuccessful. 0x80070002.    TSBootShell 7/13/2017 10:17:17 AM   904 (0x0388)
>   End program:    TSBootShell 7/13/2017 10:17:17 AM   904 (0x0388)
>   Finalizing logging from process 896 TSBootShell 7/13/2017 10:17:17 AM   904 (0x0388)
>   Finalizing logs to root of first available drive    TSBootShell 7/13/2017 10:17:17 AM   904 (0x0388)
>   LOGGING: Setting log directory to "C:\SMSTSLog".    TSBootShell 7/13/2017 10:17:17 AM   904 (0x0388)

Can someone please help me figure out why I cant pull down the images to image machines?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue like this with 2012R2 SP1 aswell.
I added a new bootimage using the same source as the old one, could you try that?